# Animated rich interactive backgrounds for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, animation

Hey everybody, this is not really a question, I have just written an article on Code Project on how to create [rich interactive backgrounds for Silverlight applications](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/ActDynBackgrounds.aspx). This background reacts to a users mouse movements and causes a fluid animation of the background elements.

Comment: This isn't really a question so probably doesn't belong here.  Looks good though!

Answer (score 0):

You can view a [live online sample](http://www.bluemarble.co.za/Applications/ActiveDynamicBackground/index.html) as well.